# Geometry of angular variables

Tags: geometry, angle

Angular variables have an interesting property in that for some applications, e.g. angle at which the light beam of a lighthouse is pointing, we expect some functions of that variable to not depend on how many times the beam has rotated around its axis. In other words $f(x) = f(x+n \ 2 \pi) \ \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It seems to me that in such cases the real line is not a convenient representation of this kind of variables. A closed curve would be more natural. However, in my limited perspective of mathematics, a curve would need to live in a space of at least 2 dimensions even if the angle space is 1-dimensional. It is disconcerting for me to need 2 dimensions to represent something that is clearly 1-dimensional.

I want to learn more about this kind of spaces but I'm a bit at a loss about how to describe the problem and try to undersand better its geometry. What branch of mathematics studies this sort of problems? Is this a case of non-Euclidean geometry?

Comment: It's just a circle, same as on a clock. Is it disconcerting to you to need a 2-dimensional clockface to represent 1-dimensional time?

Comment: I would argue that it's not necessarily a circle, any closed curve embedded in a space of dimension 2 or more would work. I'm looking for the area of mathematics that studies this sort of spaces which "wrap around" and can be better understood by "lifting" them to a higher dimensional space instead of using Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: OK, in higher math terms, what you are doing is taking the closed interval $[0,1]$, putting on an equivalence relation whereby you declare zero and one to be equivalent, and then you are considering the quotient of the interval by the equivalence relation. So, the keyphrases are "equivalence relation" and "quotient space" (or maybe "quotient construction"). But you haven't told me whether you consider clocks to be disconcerting.

Comment: Thanks. The idea of quotient space seems very relevant. And no, I don't find clocks disconcerting. I can even imagine a roller coaster moving at a constant speed and doing exactly one "lap" every 12 hours.